# Series expansion of $\sin x/x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The Taylor expansion of $\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^{n}$.

So dividing by $x$ gives $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^n$.

But this involves swapping $1/x$ with the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^{n}$. How is this allowed? If $x$ is very small this is like multiplying by a very large number, so I am not sure how convergence is guaranteed. What theorem allows for the division over an infinite series?

Comment: Dividing by $x \neq 0$ has no impact on convergence. You are just multiplying across by the value ${1 \over x}$. Similar to multiplying by a constant.

Comment: @copper.hat Don't we need a radius of convergence for an infinite series to converge?

Comment: If there was a non zero constant term in the original series then the series would have a ${1 \over x}$ term, so you would no longer have a power/Taylor series. The radius of convergence is determined by the 'tail' of the $a_n$ terms, and shifting by a constant number of terms does not affect the radius of convergence. For intuition, suppose the ratio test applies; the limit is unaffected by shifting a constant amount.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic complex analysis. The singularity of $\sin(x)/x$ at $x=0$ is removable, because $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$.  After removing that singularity, you have a function that is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ (and in fact entire).

Comment: I don't think you need complex analysis here. The limit $\sin x/ x =1$ can be (and, in fact, usually is) proven geometrically, even on the precalculus level, and the concept of removable singularity does not call for the use of complex analysis either

Answer (score 2):

The possibly very large number you are multiplying by is the same for each term of the sum, i.e. it doesn't depend on $n$, so it doesn't affect convergence.

It's the same argument that says if

$$\sum_n 1/n^2$$

converges, then so does

$$\sum_n 1,000,000,000/n^2$$
and it converges to $1,000,000,000$ times the original series. This is basic series manipulation.

And since your original series converges to $\sin x$ for $x \ne 0$, then the modified series converges to $\frac{1 }{ x}\cdot \sin x$ for non-zero $x$.

As for what happens at zero, the series clearly sums to $1$, but as for the expression "$\frac{\sin x}{x}$", people love to argue over whether this should automatically be considered to be defined at $0$ or not, and maybe the answer is different depending if we are in $\mathbb R$, or in $\mathbb C$. But your question doesn't ask about that, so we can ignore it. :-)